# CPLEX VRP subtour

Tags: cplex, opl

Im currently coding PVRP on CPLEX. I needed a constraint which finds subtours and adds a constraint which prohibits subtour. In that sense, I used CPLEX library TSP subtour example, however when I run the model it gets into loop and runs forever.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us a piece of your code please :)

Comment: The file is too large unfortunately, please give me your e-mail and I will send it to you.

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I've used the MTZ model. It's good and simple.

[MTZ model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKWKA.png)

The solution time depends on the subtours generated by the model

Regards!